# 14.04 VNC xstartup file

Tags: 14.04, vnc

I updated to 14.04 to do some testing, and now VNC is hosed. I installed gnome-classic to see if that helped but it did not. Here is my xstartup:

```
!/bin/sh
Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources xsetroot -solid grey vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
gnome-session -session=gnome-classic &
```

I have been reading everything I can find on the interwebs for hours.

Does anyone have an xstartup that works with 14.01?

Comment: I understand what he want.
He actually get a gray screen when he set up a vnc-server, and get connected to it with tight-vnc. the solution, is down there (at the answer). not perfect, but it the only one works for me.

Comment: Yes, i got same usually when setup new desktop environments, like VPS to get UI. It's not easy for a newbie to know about those things and even for usual linux users to know xstartups scripts. But we are lucky, we have the stackoverflow! @billyc answer has worked for me too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best you can get is based on the links of
https://medium.com/linux-operation-system/5e6fac849ea3

It actually does not have "desktop" but using gnome-terminal to start like firefox, nautilus, or google-chrome, ... etc. for desktop Apps. BTW I install ubuntu-gnome 14.04 not ubuntu 14.04. So I do not have to install gnome-classical or -fallback ...etc. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Agree with @guntbert. The link https://medium.com/linux-operation-system/5e6fac849ea3 was a lof helpful. Open it and Ctrl+f for "back to vnc" and you are on it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Your link to a Medium article, https://medium.com/linux-operation-system/5e6fac849ea3 is dead.  Do you have a summary of what it said?